# Keeping a NSMutableArray full of custom objects availble through whole class

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsmutablearray, custom-object

My NSMutableArray full of Article (a custom class containing an NSString * title) objects gets loaded properly in one method (checked in debugger), but when another method is called the Article objects seem to 'forget' a number of class variables (like the title variable).

Here is the code that loads the Article objects into the NSMutableArray:

```
for(int i=0;i<[articleURLs count];i++) {
    Article * a = [[Article alloc] init];
    [a initWithWebsite:[articleURLs objectAtIndex:i]];
    if([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"Features"]) [featuresArticles addObject:a];
    if([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"News"]) [newsArticles addObject:a];
    if([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"Sports"]) [sportsArticles addObject:a];
    if([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"Leisure"]) [leisureArticles addObject:a];
    if([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"Voices"]) [voicesArticles addObject:a];
    if([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"Editorial"]) [editorialArticles addObject:a];
    if([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"Page 13"]) [page13Articles addObject:a];
    [a release];
}
```

and here is the code in another method that looks for these values:

```
NSString *cellValue = @"ddd";
//NSArray * tempArray;
Article * a;
if([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"Features"]) a = [featuresArticles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"News"]) a = [newsArticles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"Sports"]) a = [sportsArticles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"Leisure"]) a = [leisureArticles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"Voices"]) a = [voicesArticles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"Editorial"]) a = [editorialArticles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([sectionTitle isEqualToString:@"Page 13"]) a = [page13Articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cellValue = [a getTitle];
```

I have been stuck on this for over 24 hours now, and the internet is not helping. Any suggestions?

Comment: Rather than have a huge number of array variables, why not have a single NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary variable contain your arrays based on the keys you have (`@"Features"`, `@"News"`, etc.)?

Comment: For example, you could have an NSDictionary called `articles`, and to add an article to a particular category, you would do: `[[articles objectForKey:sectionTitle] addObject:a];`, and to obtain it again, you would use `[[articles objectForKey:sectionTitle] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`.

Comment: By "class variable", you mean "instance variable" (ivar), correct?  Since the `title` ivar is one of the problematic variables, could we see how it is declared and and example of how you are assigning.  (i.e. the `Articles` `@interface` block...

Comment: The only setup you will require in this case, is to make sure that the dictionary contains the mutable arrays already before you try to add or get objects, by doing something like `[articles setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:@"Features"];` and similar for each category.

Answer (score 0):

Your property is probably not properly declared in your class's interface. It should look similar to this:

```
@interface Article : NSObject
{
}

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *title;

@end
```

`copy` is best for string properties because if you set the property using a mutable string, then your class will make an immutable copy of the string. If you simply `retain` it, then the mutable string may change without your class knowing about it.

Comment: I had it retain it, changed it to copy, but it still does not work.  I will try your dictionary reccomendation (out of practice, much better option anyway) and get back to you

Comment: The NSMutableDictionary use is much cleaner... but still no luck.  The title variable is not retained.  Is it being overwritten somehow that I am missing. Thanks for all of your help

Comment: @eaganr: There may be an issue elsewhere in your code. Sometimes memory leaks manifest themselves in very strange ways. Profile your code with the Instruments tools to get an idea of what is happening. It may be a problem with how you are allocating your `Article` class rather than how you assign titles to it.

Answer (score 0):

In custom class (Article), I needed to write `[title retain];` after I was finished setting it in the class Article.m file.